# isSavingPost() for widgets

Tags: widgets, block-editor, autosave

I want to get the block ID of my widgets (e.g. `#block-1`, which is displayed on the frontend after saving a widget) on the widgets screen in the backend. What I try to achieve is to display the ID of the widget in the toolbar so that you can easily copy it.
[image: copy widget ID]

I currently use a custom API endpoint to receive the ID but it will trigger a request on every render (I already debounced it, but am searching for a better way).

My idea was than to subscribe to the save action of the widgets, since the ID is first available after saving the widgets screen:

```
const widgetIdToolbar = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockEdit ) => {
    if ( select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPostType() ) {
        return BlockEdit;
    }
    
    return ( props ) => {
        if ( props.name === 'core/widget-area' || props.name === 'core/legacy-widget' ) {
            return ( <BlockEdit { ...props } /> );
        }
        
        const [ widgetId, setWidgetId ] = useState( 0 );

        subscribe( () => {
            const isAutosavingPost = select( 'core/editor' ).isAutosavingPost();
            const isSavingPost = select( 'core/editor' ).isSavingPost();
                
            if ( isSavingPost || isAutosavingPost ) {
                // do stuff
            }
        } );
        
        return (
            <>
                <BlockEdit { ...props } />
            </>
        );
    }
}, 'widgetIdToolbar' );

addFilter( 'editor.BlockEdit', 'rh-widget-toolbar/add-toolbar', widgetIdToolbar );
```

Unfortunately, both `isAutosavingPost` and `isSavingPost` always return `false`. It seems they don’t apply to widgets. How to get the similar functionality for “on widgets save”?

Comment: widgets are implemented as a legacy widget block that wraps around the widget to provide a compatibility layer, though in this case it shouldn't matter, the root problem is that the widgets screen is not a post editor so there is no main post to autosave. As an aside, what are you trying to do that requires this?

Comment: also is this on the edit widgets screen, or the customizer screen?

Comment: As I said, I want to get the block ID of the widgets in the backend, which is then displayed as ID in the frontend. This ID is first available after saving the widgets and not before (except for blocks that use server-side rendering). Thus I want to subscribe to the save action to get the ID directly afterwards.
It’s the dedicated widgets screen I’m talking about. Will update the question accordingly.

Comment: I see, what are you trying to do when this happens that requires it though? Needing the block ID is usually a sign that you're doing something wrong, or that a much simpler solution is present that you're unaware of. If you can provide the context then those can be shared, or it'll avoid unnecessary questions. It's also possible that someone will provide an answer that while technically correct, can't be used in your situation.

Comment: Also, where did you put the subscribe code in your question? Is it enqueued on that page or is it included some other way only when that widget runs? Or on a particular event? Are you trying to use the block ID to traverse upwards or across or to get the sidebar ID?

Comment: I want to get the block ID so that it can be copied right in the widget area without the requirement to look it up in the frontend so that it can be used in the custom CSS.

I use the subscribe inside the `editor.BlockEdit` filter.

Comment: I updated the code for a better context.

Comment: hmm would it make more sense to re-add the advanced panel from the post editor that inserts a HTML class so it appears in the sidebar of all widgets? It doesn't solve your question, but it does solve your original problem if it can be done, and I expect it will be easier

Comment: e.g. https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/#editor-blockedit to insert a panel that you can then use to display the block ID or html class you wanted, then you wouldn't need to break out of the widget to get the block, you could use more conventional means via the `props`

Comment: Oh, I think you misunderstood about the "block ID". I don’t mean the client ID by this, but the actual HTML ID in the end, e.g. `#block-1`, `#block-2`, etc. This value is only available after saving the widgets and has nothing to do with the client ID. This is why I want to subscribe to the save action.

Comment: You mean on the _front_ end? You mentioned that it's only available when the widget is saved but you have not shared how you're acquiring that or where you're sourcing that information from, or is acquiring it also a part of the question? Make sure your question is comprehensive and doesn't leave anything out, try not to ommit details in the name of being concise

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: I added more details what I currently achieved and how it looks like. Maybe you get a better idea if it.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to display the block ID so that the user can get it easily, instead try using a block editor filter to add a panel in the sidebar:

From: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/#editor-blockedit

```
const { createHigherOrderComponent } = wp.compose;
const { Fragment } = wp.element;
const { InspectorControls } = wp.blockEditor;
const { PanelBody } = wp.components;
 
const withInspectorControls = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockEdit ) => {
    return ( props ) => {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <BlockEdit { ...props } />
                <InspectorControls>
                    <PanelBody>My custom control</PanelBody>
                </InspectorControls>
            </Fragment>
        );
    };
}, 'withInspectorControl' );
 
wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'editor.BlockEdit',
    'my-plugin/with-inspector-controls',
    withInspectorControls
);
```

Then inside the panel, use `props` to retrieve the blocks ID and display it, perhaps in an input with the `disabled` property. Specifically `clientId`.

It might look like this (untested):

```
const { createHigherOrderComponent } = wp.compose;
const { Fragment } = wp.element;
const { InspectorControls } = wp.blockEditor;
const { PanelBody } = wp.components;
 
const withWidgetIDPanel = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockEdit ) => {
    return ( props ) => {
        const widgetID = props.__internalWidgetId ? props.__internalWidgetId : 0;
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <BlockEdit { ...props } />
                <InspectorControls>
                    <PanelBody>
                        <input
                            class="components-text-control__input"
                            type="text"
                            disabled
                            value={ props.widgetID }
                        />
                    </PanelBody>
                </InspectorControls>
            </Fragment>
        );
    };
}, 'withWidgetIDPanel' );
 
wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'editor.BlockEdit',
    'tomjn/display-widget-id',
    withWidgetIDPanel
);
```

This will give you the widget ID if it's available in the sidebar for every legacy widget if enqueued on the widgets page, and provides a useful debug panel for non-widget editors too. It also gives you a place to use react hooks and other WordPress APIs in the context of a specific block, without needing to figure out which widget belongs to which block ID.

Note that when the widget ID changes, React will re-render the component automatically, no subscription is necessary. Note that no local state is in use.

### Frontend Block ID

If however you want the ID that gets used on the frontend, there's an attribute named `__internalWidgetId`. **When this changes React will re-render the edit component because its props have changed, so no subscription to the store is necessary.**

Before the widget is saved, this `__internalWidgetId` attribute does not exist, and will be `null` if accessed, and when it comes into existence again the edit component will re-render because changed props are how React knows to re-render a DOM element.

Storing the widget ID in local state is not necessary and could lead to problems. Just pass the raw attribute down if it's not null to any child components that need it or use the internal widget ID directly.

As a bonus, you can select on the `core/edit-widgets` store to grab the widget data directly.

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I could see, the `__internalWidgetId` is only available on blocks that use server-side rendering (or when the `save` function returns `null`), which does not apply to most of the blocks.

Comment: that's because only legacy widgets are actually widgets and have a widget ID, for other blocks the technical answer is no, they don't have a widget ID because they're not really widgets, they're just blocks. For those you should rely on the existing block based solution of the advanced panel with its HTML anchor ( aka the ID ) and the css class

Comment: At a stretch, `getWidgets` in the `core/edit-widgets` store may provide a psuedo ID you can use for non-widget blocks, perhaps combining the block ID with `getWidget(`, this seems to provide an `id` attribute as well as some wrapping HTML

Comment: I'd also suggest `useSelect` instead of subscribing so that re-rendering is used, this storing the widget ID in local state is a massive can of worms that backfires